# How to create Public api key for a google project

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-directory-api

How to setup a google project api key.i want to use google directory apis. and have to retrieve user's list in the domain.In google Api explorer(https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/directory.users.list) i authorized and get the list of all users in my domain.but when i use node.js for retrieving the users's list in response i am getting

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

here is small snippet of node.js code

```
var request = require('request');

    var request1 = {url : 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users',
    headers :{'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+bodyy.access_token},query:{
        domain : 'iritesh.com',key:'AIzaSyBrTEYAap74npiUhKWGp0eLcPY1kBMnTIk'
    },method : 'GET'};
    request(request1,function(err,ress,body){
        console.log('body is');
        console.log(body);
    res.render('index',{title: 'Express'});

    });
```

i doubt i am getting this error because i didn't set up public key properly.my system ip address is 103.245.XX.XX and i have setup same IP address in Project console.can anyone please guideline what should i fill in allowed Server IP addresses when i am using localhost.am i doing any mistake??i enabled API Access in Admin Console also.my system admin is ritesh@iritesh.com and domain is iritesh.com.temporarily i hardcoded it,please ignore this.i am attaching snapshot related to that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for starters Users: list requires  authorization which means you will need to use Open authentication and **not** a public API key.

Documentation for [users: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list)

```
Users: list    
Requires authorization
```

Answer: your code doesn't work because you are trying to use a public api key with a API that requires Authentication.

Comment: i am using authorization.first i used OAuth 2.0 flow and get access token of Admin account.and i sent in headers Authorization containing access token.so my request is authorized.Please respond if i am taking it wrong ??

Comment: Are you using a Client ID for web application ?  The picture you posted shows "Key for browser applications" which is next to public access, which is not oauth2 and only used for public access apis like Google books Google url Shortner where you don't need to be authenticated. Which one are you using?

Comment: yes,i am using client ID and OAuth2 flow and when you see https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#auth url and make a call as admin it also including a key parameter in url.in this key parameter i am using Public API Key.perhaps in Directory Api both are required .i have to send access_token in header and public key in key parameter.but when i remove key parameter in request still i m getting same error.PLease respond how to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your code:

```
bodyy.access_token
```

should maybe be?

```
body.access_token
```

Comment: no it was a rough code it was not by mistake.will clean this code very soon